# Why capturing binary data in Filter Servlet fails in the following code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters, binary-data

I have a java servlet application where I want to capture the response body and then do some processing. I am using servlet filter for capturing the response. The problem I am facing is that I am not sure how to capture the binary response (sorry I am new to servlets and all). Following is the implementation:

#### Filter Code

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    HttpServletRequest request =  (HttpServletRequest)req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;
    //If I change CharResponseWrapper by ByteResponseWrapper then I get 0 length content
    CharResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response);
    if ( null != filterChain){
        filterChain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);
    }
    response.getOutputStream().write(wrappedResponse.toString().getBytes());
}
```

#### ByteResponseWrapper

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

public class ByteResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
{
    private ByteArrayOutputStream output;
    public ByteResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(output.size());
        return new String(output.toByteArray());
    }
    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }
}
```

#### CharResponseWrapper

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private StringWriter output;
    public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        output = new StringWriter();
    }
    public String toString() {
        return output.toString();
    }
    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }
}
```

Any idea why using `ByteResponseWrapper` gives zero body response? Please suggest if I am missing something or not doing correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're converting it to a `String` then back to a `byte` array. That will encode it to be printable, which won't work for arbitrary binary data.

You might try instead adding a `toBytes()` method to your `ByteResponseWrapper` that simply returns `output.toByteArray()` then:

```
return response.getOutputStream().write(wrappedResponse.toBytes());
```

Obviously, this same line won't work for your `CharResponseWrapper`, so if you need both, you'll need additional logic to handle them differently.

(Similarly, returning a `PrintWriter` for binary data doesn't make sense. `Writers` are for text.)